# How to ignore last digit and compare two strings using Groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have two compare two Strings a = "123456" and b="123457". I would like to compare them in Groovy scripting. String a has to match string b ignoring the last character. It means it has to match anything with "12345\d". How to write it programmatically?

Comment: `if (a.substring(0, a.length() - 1).equals(b.substring(0, b.length() - 1))`?

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to ignore the last character in a string is to use slicing, e.g.

```
a[0..-2] == b[0..-2]
```

Use negative numbers in the slice to represent an index from the end.